# How to detect concentric circles in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

Actually I have a power cable image and i want to measure the thickness of each layer in the cross-section of power cable. For more information, please find image as given below:

[image]

Here is the original image of cables:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code to detect concentric circle using Hough Circle method of OpenCV:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("GoldenSpike.png",0)

output = cv2.imread("GoldenSpike.png",1)
cv2.imshow("Original image", image)
cv2.waitKey()

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(11,11),0)

cv2.imshow("Blurred image", blurred)
cv2.waitKey()
setItem=set()
previous=0;
minR=4
for maxR in range(9,300,9):
    # Finds circles in a grayscale image using the Hough transform
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100,
                             param1=100,param2=100,minRadius=minR,maxRadius=maxR)
    minR+=4
    # cv2.HoughCircles function has a lot of parameters, so you can find more about it in documentation
    # or you can use cv2.HoughCircles? in jupyter nootebook to get that 

    # Check to see if there is any detection
    if circles is not None:
        # If there are some detections, convert radius and x,y(center) coordinates to integer
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

        for (x, y, r) in circles:
            # Draw the circle in the output image
            cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0,255,0), 1)
            # Draw a rectangle(center) in the output image
            cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 2, y - 2), (x + 2, y + 2), (0,255,0), -1)
            setItem.add(r)

lst=sorted(setItem)
print("Length of List =", len(lst))
for item in lst:
    print(item)

cv2.imshow("Detections",output)
cv2.imwrite("CirclesDetection.jpg",output)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Please share the original image of wire cross-section also as you will be processing that image.

Comment: Have you tried [Hough circles](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) yet?

Comment: @RahulKedia I have added original image. Please look on to that

Comment: @bfris i have tried Hough circle but detecting more circles and also different centers.

Comment: Not showing the true image when asking an image processing question is a sin.

Comment: @AsifHussain, to reduce the number of circles found, you can increase the value of param2. According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d), circles with higher accumulator values (better scores) are returned first. I presume this means they occur first in the array of circles returned. If this is true, then if you have multiple circles with similar center and similar radius, you could discard those after the first found.

Comment: @bfris i have already tried by increasing the value of param2 and that was working. how i can determine all those parameter values in cv2.HoughCircles() method on the basis of the image. I have hardcoded all those values. i just want to determine those values on the basis of the image. Can you explain?

Comment: @AsifHussain I don't know any way to pre-process in such a way that a single value of param2 will always work. You could try Adaptive or Otsu [thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). Or you could lower param2 a little bit and rely on an algorithm of throwing away duplicate circles.

Answer (score 2):

It is an easy matter to locate jumps in the pixel values along a vertical or horizontal line. This can be done to pixel accuracy or sub-pixel accuracy by linear interpolation between the two neighboring values below/above a threshold.

First draw a vertical line that crosses the cable. Then find the midpoint of the jumps that you detect. Draw an horizontal by the midpoint and detect all edges, which will tell you the number and thicknesses of the layers.

If you know the true size of the cable, you can use a proportionality rule to obtain the true thicknesses.

Comment: Here horizontal and vertical line is used for only demonstration purposes. I have edited and added original images in the post. Can you please look on to that again.

Comment: I didn't mean to use your blue lines, of course. My answer is still quite valid, though you need to ignore the edges found in the center and be more cautious about edge detection as this is a picture rather than a diagram (in fact a mixture of both, I guess). I would not use Hough circles.

Comment: can you give me an example without using Hough circle to do that?

Comment: @AsifHussain: try and understand my explanations. I am not a free coding service, sorry.